# Catch DataIntegrityViolationException in @Transactional service method

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions

I have a REST Spring boot app with Hibernate. For simplicity let's assume this workflow:

1. Controller handles incoming requests, calls Service methods
2. Service methods are `@Transactional`, do some business logic and call Persistence methods
3. Persistence methods are handled by DAO objects, saving stuff into database.

The database has a `unique` constraint on `username` of a User. The way I have it working now is this:

1. Client sends request to Controller
2. Controller calls Service
3. Service attempts to save an object through DAO. If `DataViolationException` occurs, Service returns a custom Exception
4. Controller catches the custom Exception and sends back appropriate response

---

The pseudocode is this:

```
public class UserController {
    @RequestMapping("/user")
    public User createUser(...){
        try{
            return userService.createUser(...);
        } catch (UserAlreadyExistsException e){
            // Do some processing and return error message to client
        }
    }
}

public class UserService {
    @Transactional
    public User createUser(...){
        (...)
        try{
            userDAO.save(newUserObject);
        } catch(DataIntegrityViolationException e){
            throw new UserAlreadyExistsException(username);
        }
    }
}
```

However, this way I am getting an error when a duplicate user is attempted to be created.

```
javax.persistence.RollbackException: Transaction marked as rollbackOnly
```

**One way to fix this** seems to be to let the `DataIntegrityViolationException` "bubble" up from the transaction (and not catch it in Service). But that means that the Controller has to handle persistence exceptions and I don't like that.

I prefer if the service threw "understandable" exceptions for the Controller to handle. The service knows what persistence exceptions to expect and when and is able to "translate" the broad `DataIntegrityViolationException` into a meaningful one.

Is there a way to handle the exceptions this way? I don't particularly like the idea of having a "2-layered service layer" to achieve this.

---

EDIT: Another reason I want to throw my custom Exception is that it is required by the compiler to be caught. I want to enforce the controller to handle all possible exceptions that may occur.

Comment: Then also tell the `@Transactional` that it should rollback for those exceptions. By default it only rollback for `RuntimeException`s.

Comment: Did you find a way to catch the exception in the Service and not the Controller?  I'm thinking about removing @Transaction and just handling commits and rollbacks on my own.

Comment: Please try with:
@Transactional(noRollbackFor = DataIntegrityViolationException.class)

Comment: I wasn't able to catch ex inside @Trans method. The reason is ex is thrown after transaction is finished if it has to be rollbacked. I don't see a big problem with 2 service layer where one communicate with Controller and call persistence service, where you can catch DataIntegrityViolationException, or others, and translate them to custom response. For me that is better then catch and handle service ex in Controller. mflorczak approach doesn't work for me. I am not sure what can be achieved with noRollbackFor, because insert in database will fail if data integrity is broken anyway.

Comment: I'm facing this right now as I'm trying to catch the exception and return back a custom exception message using my own exception handling class. But I only see this is possible while handling the exception in controller which I don't like either. Is there a solution for this? Catching exception in the service method which is set to @Transactional isn't working as expected. Not sure of any workaround wither :(

Answer (score 6):

Your repository need to extends JpaRepository, and when you do that. You can use saveAndFlush method from that repository. That mean, you code will be immediately executed on database and exception will be throwed before finish transaction and you will be able to catch it in Catch block. I added also sample for deleting operation.

Repository:

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

public interface UserDAO extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
}
```

Service:

```
 public class UserService {
        private UserDAO userDAO;

        (...)

        @Transactional
        public User createUser(...){
            (...)
            try{
                userDAO.saveAndFlush(newUserObject);
            } catch(DataIntegrityViolationException e){
                throw new UserAlreadyExistsException(username);
            }
        }

        @Transactional
        public void deleteUser(...){
            (...)
            try{
                userDAO.delete(deletingUserObject);
                userDAO.flush();
            } catch(DataIntegrityViolationException e){
                throw new UserException(username);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: This doesn't make sense at all. If you are expecting to execute the sql query instantly, whats the use of using @Transactional for the method in the first place? From your sample code, `userDAO.delete(deletingUserObject);` will be executed and if something went wrong after this step, you should also make sure to have a mechanism to rollback the operation which in my opinion is not easy to handle, especially if its a delete operation. In this case, I'm not sure if the @Transactional will help you in any case.

Answer (score 2):

Annotate your service method with

```
@Transactional(rollbackFor = UserAlreadyExistsException.class)
```

it will tell spring to not commit the transaction if the Exception is thrown so you will be able to catch it in your controller

Comment: What's the best way of 'understanding' which constraint was broken, for instance if there are several constraints on one entity? or constraints on different entities?

Comment: Thats right, if I have 2 unique constraints How distinguish them?

Comment: you will get constraint name in the error message

Comment: A more recent version of the same question if anyone cares to comment? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77256992/how-to-catch-check-for-uniqueness-in-spring-boot-3